# No database selected Error While Creating Table in MySQL with Java

Tags: java, mysql, exception, database-connection

I have Created a database with this code Some days ago

---

```
sql = "Create Database if not exists My_Test_Project";
            stmnt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

And Created Some tables at that time. Now I'm creating two new tables in it one with this query

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE if not exists My_Test_Project.Sales_Invoice_Help "
                    + "(inv_help_id INTEGER,"                    
                    + "item VARCHAR(255),"
                    + "qty INTEGER,"
                    + "rate DECIMAL (7, 2),"
                    + "total DECIMAL (7, 2),"
                    + "sale_inv_id INTEGER,"
                    + " PRIMARY KEY (inv_help_id),FOREIGN KEY (sale_inv_id) REFERENCES Sales_Invoice (sale_inv_id))";
            stmnt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

And when I Executed my program it throw Exception

```
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
```

But at the same time this query executed successfully

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE if not exists My_Test_Project.Sales_Invoice "
                    + "(sale_inv_id INTEGER not NULL, "
                    + "date VARCHAR(255), "
                    + "acc_name VARCHAR(255),"
                    + "due_date VARCHAR(255),"
                    + "customer_name VARCHAR(255),"
                    + "receipt_no VARCHAR(255),"
                    + "freight_charges INTEGER,"
                    + "deliver_to VARCHAR(255),"
                    + "deliver_date VARCHAR(255),"
                    + "total INTEGER,"
                    + "discount INTEGER,"
                    + "g_total INTEGER ,"
                    + " PRIMARY KEY (sale_inv_id))";
            stmnt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

**Note:** Sales_Invoice table is first in sequence and in code too.
I do not know why its throwing exception. Can you please guide me.

Comment: You didn't select a database, as the exception says. The reason why the second query works is because you specify the database _and_ the table.

Comment: @tkausl I have also specified database in `Sales_Invoice_Help` table as 
`My_Test_Project.Sales_Invoice_Help`. Where `My_Test_Project` is the name of Database.

Comment: @tkausl thanks for quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would believe in this line you will need to add the Database name:

```
REFERENCES Sales_Invoice (sale_inv_id)
```

So it should now be:

```
 REFERENCES My_Test_Project.Sales_Invoice (sale_inv_id)
```

Comment: @InzimamTariqIT Great. Can you please accept the answer?

Comment: @InzimamTariqIT My Pleasure